# Using Jquerys '.last' on a dynamically created element?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm having quite a bit of trouble figuring out how I would do this:

```
$('.add_education').click(function() {
    $('#education_form_clone:last').last().clone(true).appendTo('#education_form_container');
});
```

It doesn't select the last element if it's a newly created one. Basically I want to clone the last `#education_form_clone` (to get the values.) I understand it's because it's dynamically created and I've had to solve something like this before but I just can't figure out for the life of me how I managed it.

Comment: The main problem here is that it shouldn't be multiple elements with the same ID like `#education_form_clone`. Set class instead of ID, change the selector to `.education_form_clone` and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't have multiple elements with the same id! it's **invalid HTML**.
2. You use last twice (`:last` and `.last()`) for no good reason.

You should use `class` instead of `id`:

```
$('.add_education').click(function() {
    $('.education_form_clone:last').clone(true).appendTo('#education_form_container');
});
```

Comment: Fixed it thanks. I'm aware that you can't use IDs twice, it was just something I slapped together without thinking about it haha. Cheers.

Comment: Working perfectly thanks. Just as a note, The whole ':last, and .last()' thing was me clutching at straws and forgetting to remove it before I pasted it on here!

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `education_form_clone` `</div>` to a class you could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="edutcation_form_container">
    <div class="education_form_clone">Education Form Element</div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="add_education">Click Me to Clone</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('.add_education').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $clone = $('.education_form_clone').filter(':last').clone();
    $('#edutcation_form_container .education_form_clone').filter(':last').after($clone);

    console.log($clone);
});​
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jFgQW/2/)